# Wordpress Child Theme Path

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on my first child theme and I'm running into a lot of confusion with directories and child themes.

I won't use my real website but I have made a directory in my cPanel dedicated to working on my theme which is at www.wp.example.com

Lets call the template testTemplate. I made a child template called testTemplate-child following the Wordpress codex meaning I registered the parent theme in the child theme's function.php

So wp.example.com loads the style from both the parent theme and the child theme which is desired. What it does not load is the javascript files I enqueued in my child theme's functions.php file.

The confusing part is this, if I navigate to www.wp.example.com/testTemplate-child/ my javascript loads up and works.

I'm wondering if anyone can clear this up for me, why does my child's function.php only work in wp.example.com/testTemplate-child.

Comment: On the server, does the public html /testTemplate-child directory exist? Does it have an entire WordPress install or anything like that?

Comment: Do you have any JS error?

Comment: @TaylorCampbell both the parent and child theme are under: public_html/wp/wp-content/themes/

Comment: @Skatox no errors at all, in wp.example.com the javascript doesn't load at all

Comment: Did my answer worked? Select it if worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your child's theme **function.php** is added before parent's function.php, that's why you can't override some options, also keep in mind that you'll need to call `get_stylesheet_directory()` to get child's theme path, because if you do another function, it will load parent's path.

Example to load a javascript file located a **/js** folder:

```
$jsPath = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/js/yourScript.js';
wp_enqueue_script( 'child-js', $jsPath, array(), '1.0', true )
```

More info at: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: I understand that now but all I'm doing in the child theme is adding a function to load a couple scripts then adding them using addaction. Do I need to put that in the parent theme?

Comment: The problem of adding it to parent theme, is that on any update you'll overwrite any change. You can control the order of loading with the depedencie option (array() at my answer). I haven't use addaction.